# C++ Event Emitter

Tags: c++, c++11, event-handling, template-meta-programming

I needed an event bus in C++ with a few features:

- Possibility to add/remove both functions and member methods.
- Ability to remove automatically those listeners that wrap member methods of expired classes.
- Easy to use registration facilities to attach member methods as listeners.

The last point is quite important, for I want to avoid having dedicated functions to register listeners that must be modified whenever a new event takes part in the game. In particular, I was looking for a solution for which the following lines of code are enough:

```
S s;
emitter.reg(s);
```

And that's all, even if in the future it arises the requirement for one more listener for a new event to be added to `S`.

It follows an implementation of such an *event bus*.

<sub>I know that one of the first questions will be *why don't you use the `std::function`?*. Well, nothing against the `std::function` and I'm sure that it's a better solution, more flexible and with higher performance. I actually use it, but I was experimenting and looking for a slightly different approach, aimed to match my laziness and a few other requirements. The following *event bus* has some features that are pretty useful to me and sometimes I use it for them.</sub>

**signal.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace eventpp {

template<typename E>
class Signal {
    using InstanceType = std::weak_ptr<void>;
    using CallType = bool(*)(std::weak_ptr<void> &, const E &);

    template<void(*F)(const E &)>
    static bool stub(std::weak_ptr<void> &, const E &event) {
        F(event);
        return true;
    }

    template<class C, void(C::*M)(const E &) = &C::receive>
    static bool stub(std::weak_ptr<void> &wptr, const E &event) {
        bool ret = false;

        if(!wptr.expired()) {
            std::shared_ptr<C> ptr = std::static_pointer_cast<C>(wptr.lock());
            (ptr.get()->*M)(event);
            ret = true;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    struct Call {
        InstanceType instance;
        CallType call;

        bool operator==(const Call &other) const noexcept {
            return instance.lock() == other.instance.lock() &&
                    call == other.call;
        }
    };

public:
    template<void(*F)(const E &)>
    void add() {
        remove<F>();
        Call call = { std::weak_ptr<void>{}, &stub<F> };
        calls.emplace_back(call);
    }

    template<class C, void(C::*M)(const E &)>
    void add(std::weak_ptr<C> &ptr) {
        remove<C, M>(ptr);
        Call call = { ptr, &stub<C, M> };
        calls.emplace_back(call);
    }

    template<void(*F)(const E &)>
    void remove() {
        Call call = { std::weak_ptr<void>{}, &stub<F> };
        calls.erase(std::remove(calls.begin(), calls.end(), call), calls.end());
    }

    template<class C, void(C::*M)(const E &)>
    void remove(std::weak_ptr<C> &ptr) {
        Call call = { ptr, &stub<C, M> };
        calls.erase(std::remove(calls.begin(), calls.end(), call), calls.end());
    }

    void publish(const E &event) {
        for(auto it = calls.rbegin(), end = calls.rend(); it != end; it++) {
            bool valid = (it->call)(it->instance, event);

            if(!valid) {
                calls.erase(std::next(it).base());
            }
        }
    }

    std::size_t size() const noexcept {
        return calls.size();
    }

private:
    std::vector<Call> calls;
};

}
```

**bus.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include "signal.hpp"

namespace eventpp {

namespace details {

template<class E>
struct ETag { using type = E; };

template<int N, int M>
struct Choice: public Choice<N+1, M> { };

template<int N>
struct Choice<N, N> { };

}

template<class D>
struct Receiver: public std::enable_shared_from_this<D>
{ };

template<int S, class... T>
class BusBase;

template<int S, class E, class... O>
class BusBase<S, E, O...>: public BusBase<S, O...> {
    using Base = BusBase<S, O...>;

protected:
    using Base::get;
    using Base::reg;

    Signal<E>& get(details::ETag<E>) {
        return signal;
    }

    template<class C>
    auto reg(details::Choice<S-(sizeof...(O)+1), S>, std::weak_ptr<C> ptr)
    -> decltype(std::declval<C>().receive(std::declval<E>())) {
        signal.template add<C, &C::receive>(ptr);
        Base::reg(details::Choice<S-sizeof...(O), S>{}, ptr);
    }

    std::size_t size() const noexcept {
        return signal.size() + Base::size();
    }

private:
    Signal<E> signal;
};

template<int S>
class BusBase<S> {
protected:
    virtual ~BusBase() { }
    void get();
    void reg(details::Choice<S, S>, std::weak_ptr<void>) { }
    std::size_t size() const noexcept { return 0; }
};

template<class... T>
class Bus: public BusBase<sizeof...(T), T...> {
    using Base = BusBase<sizeof...(T), T...>;

public:
    using Base::size;

    template<class E, void(*F)(const E &)>
    void add() {
        Signal<E> &signal = Base::get(details::ETag<E>{});
        signal.template add<F>();
    }

    template<class C, template<typename> class P>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<P<C>, std::weak_ptr<C>>::value, void>::type
    reg(P<C> &ptr) {
        auto wptr = static_cast<std::weak_ptr<C>>(ptr);
        Base::reg(details::Choice<0, sizeof...(T)>{}, wptr);
    }

    template<class E, class C, void(C::*M)(const E &) = &C::receive, template<typename> class P>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<P<C>, std::weak_ptr<C>>::value, void>::type
    add(P<C> &ptr) {
        Signal<E> &signal = Base::get(details::ETag<E>{});
        auto wptr = static_cast<std::weak_ptr<C>>(ptr);
        signal.template add<C, M>(wptr);
    }

    template<class E, void(*F)(const E &)>
    void remove() {
        Signal<E> &signal = Base::get(details::ETag<E>{});
        signal.template remove<F>();
    }

    template<class E, class C, void(C::*M)(const E &) = &C::receive, template<typename> class P>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<P<C>, std::weak_ptr<C>>::value, void>::type
    remove(P<C> &ptr) {
        Signal<E> &signal = Base::get(details::ETag<E>{});
        auto wptr = static_cast<std::weak_ptr<C>>(ptr);
        signal.template remove<C, M>(wptr);
    }

    template<class E, class... A>
    void publish(A&&... args) {
        Signal<E> &signal = Base::get(details::ETag<E>{});
        E e(std::forward<A>(args)...);
        signal.publish(e);
    }
};

}
```

**example of use**

```
// ...

struct E1 { };
struct E2 { };
struct E3 { };

struct S {
    void receive(const E1 &) { }
    void receive(const E3 &) { }
};

// ...

std::shared_ptr<S> ptr = std::make_shared<S>();
Bus<E1, E2, E3> bus;

// it registers only and both the methods named received in s
bus.reg(ptr);

bus.publish<E1>(); // received by s
bus.publish<E2>(); // no listeners
bus.publish<E3>(); // received by s
```

---

<sub>[Here](https://github.com/skypjack/eventpp) is the full code of the project, with a bunch of tests and a brief documentation.</sub>